# Make a application folder for images

Tags: java, android, file

Whenever i save a picture, it goes to /storage/emulated/0/tracker/imgname.jpg, but i want it to save in /storage/emulated/tracker/imgname.jpg

```
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(uri.getPath());
    File dir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/Tracker");
    dir.mkdir();
    File file = new File (dir, "img" + System.currentTimeMillis() + ".jpg");

    try {
        FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, out);
        out.flush();
        out.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    Intent mediaScanIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE);
    mediaScanIntent.setData(uri);
    context.sendBroadcast(mediaScanIntent);
```

Comment: You cannot write to `/storage/emulated/`.

Comment: I not trying to save to sd card, just to internal storage of the phone. If it must go to /storage/emulated/0 so be it, i just whant that the name of the folder i see in my gallery app will be "Tracker".